# Excel marco on copy and paste to specific blank columns

Tags: excel, vba

Need help with a simple excel macro.  I have data in sheet 1 column X1 through X20.  I want to autmatically paste this information to column A and then when I update the numbers in Column X I want to paste this information to Column B and then to Column C... I only need to do this 12 times. Here is the simple macro I tried.

```
Workbooks("copynpaste2.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("X1:X20").copy _ 
destination:=Workbooks("copynpaste2.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1)
```

Comment: Change Range("P1:P20") to Range("X1:X20").  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Worksheet_Change` event. With this event, each time you change column X, the code will fire and copy to columns A... B... C... And you will never have to manually run any code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("X1:X20")) Is Nothing Then 'only do this when making changes to X1:X20

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If IsEmpty(Me.Range("A1")) Then

        Me.Range("A1:A20").Value = Me.Range("X1:X20").Value

    ElseIf IsEmpty(Me.Range("B1")) Then

        Me.Range("B1:B20").Value = Me.Range("X1:X20").Value

    Else

        Me.Range("A1:A20").End(xlToRight).Offset(, 1).Value = Me.Range("X1:X20").Value

    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End If
```

Place this code inside the [Worksheet Module](http://www.contextures.com/xlvba01.html#Worksheet) on the sheet where the data is located.

Comment: Thank you for your help... I got an error on this line: if intersect(target, Me.Range.....  Thank you.

Comment: Yes it works.  Thank you so much.  Also if I want to paste only the values (since X1:X20 are formula's), can you insert that code in as well.  Thank you.

Comment: @S.Nair - It already does that no? `Me.Range("X1:X20").**Value**`

Comment: oh you are right... :)  You are awesome Scott. I was having an issue with it.  Everything worked fine when I did it on a test sheet but when I actually copied the code to my report sheet it's not working.  I think the reason is column X1:X20 numbers are generated from a macro that pulls up the data from our internal website. So when I run the macro the numbers on X1:X20 generates but doesn't copy the values on to A1:A20.  Then when I do a copy and paste over X1:X20 the code works.  Strange!  Thanks for your help man...

Comment: @S.Nair - Try the `Worksheet_Calculate` method. That may work with the other macro pulling the data from the website. Not sure how that macro works, but if the `Calculate` method doesn't work, then just embed this macro into the macro that pulls the data from the website. It's not working with the on_change event because however the macro populates the numbers onto the sheet is not being recognized as a cell change in Excel. Lastly, if this answer (or the other) satisfies your original question **as asked** please mark one as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
Sub dothis()
    Dim c As Long
    For c = 1 To 12
        If Cells(1, c) = "" Then
            Range("X1:X20").Copy 
            Range(Cells(1, c), Cells(20, c)).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Each time you run the macro it will check if cell 1 in columns A:L is blank and copy cells X1:X20 to the first empty column.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Comment: Hi Chris, Thank you for helping me.  Need help with few more on the same topic.  Want to copy and paste special values to another sheet using the same macro.  Right now I have formulas on X1:X20.  Thank you Thank you

Comment: Hi Chris the code works. Thank you.  Any chance you can add in a code that would paste special values and number formats. Thank you.